# How to return text to a span in a .cshtml from a controller in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I just have a question that I do not know if it is even possible.  I have been searching around and have not found anything.  I am curious that if there is anyway that in my Login Controller.  If one of my if statements fail is there any way that I could return some text to a span on my Login view?

So say this fails during my log in method in my login controller:

```
if (BadCredentials(checkLogin) == null)
{
     return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");               
}
```

Is there any way that I could set that to return text to this span instead of a redirect?

```
<span class="help-block"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller :

```
if (BadCredentials(checkLogin) == null)
{
     ViewBag.SpanText = "This is span text";         
}
```

Your View:

```
<span class="help-block">@ViewBag.SpanText</span>
```

Comment: You both are awesome! Thank you will mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value in [ViewBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and use it in `View`

*In controller*

```
if (BadCredentials(checkLogin) == null)
{
     ViewBag.YourValue = "some text";
}
```

*In View*

```
<span class="help-block">@ViewBag.YourValue</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Viewbag property to display data from controller to view in .cshtml like

### in your controller :

ViewBag.Name = "your text";

### in your .cshtml :

@ViewBag.Name

Answer (score 0):

On your Controller

```
@{

    var ImageFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Document/Picture/" + @Request.Cookies["sTimeStamp"].Value + ".jpg");
    var PanFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Document/PAN/" + @Request.Cookies["sTimeStamp"].Value + ".jpg");
    var AdhaarFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Document/Adhaar/" + @Request.Cookies["sTimeStamp"].Value + ".jpg");

}
@if (System.IO.File.Exists(ImageFile) == false || System.IO.File.Exists(PanFile) == false || System.IO.File.Exists(AdhaarFile) == false)
{
    ViewBag.KycMessage = "Your KYC has not completed yet. KYC is mandatory to get payment you earned. Following is list of document which is not uploaded.";
}
else
{
    ViewBag.KycMessage = "<span style=\"color:green\">KYC Comlete</span>";
}

<span>@ViewBag.KycMessage</span>
```